# A new cabinet has been sworn in (in) Dhaka

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

'Swear in' is a phrasal verb. Do I need to add another preposition after the phrasal verb - in this case 'in' - if I want to mention the name of the place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need the preposition:

> A new cabinet has been sworn in in Dhaka.

This is correct, but the double "in" is slightly odd, so you might choose to rephrase. In spoken English, the phrase "sworn in" would be pronounced as one word, making the double "in" less of a problem.

Comment: Some people would write 'sworn-in', which improves the appearance.

Comment: How do you pronounce 'sworn in' as 'one word'?

Comment: as "swornin",  there is a single stress centre

Comment: Well, I deal with swearing-in of constables, and there are two 'stress centres' when we do it.

Comment: I also doubt it’s possible to detect any pronunciation difference between “sworn in” treated as one word compared to two. Instead I think some native speakers might be inclined to introduce a very small pause between “sworn in” and “in Dhaka”.